# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined angular 2

Tags: json, angular, get

I am moving my get's to a different service.ts for my application but I get this 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNaoF.png)

Here is my code:
AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {FeatureService} from "./Feature.service";


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [FeatureService],
    template: `<h1>Hier staat de json die we uit de test hebben gehaald</h1>
                <p>Deze json hallen we van vert.x af en kunnen we converten naar een mooie rapport.</p>
                <button (click)="clicked()">Haal test Json op</button>
                <button (click)="getFeatures()">features</button>
                <button (click)="getScenarios()">scenarios</button>
                {{leerling}}

                `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  titel = "";
  leerling: any;
  leerlingUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/testresultaten';

    public clicked(){
      this.http.get(this.leerlingUrl).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => this.leerling = JSON.stringify(data)
          ,error => this.leerling = "error", () => console.log("Json got good"));
    }
    public getFeatures(){
      this.leerling = FeatureService.getFeature();
    }
    public getScenarios(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/features/1/scenarios').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => this.leerling = JSON.stringify(data),error => this.leerling = "error", () => console.log("Json got good"));
  }

constructor(private http : Http, private featureService : FeatureService){
}

 }
```

And here is my Feature.service.ts

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

export class FeatureService{
  private static http : Http;


  static getFeature(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/features')
      .map(data => data.toString());
  }
}
```

The Old ones (clicked() and getScenarios()) still work but FeatureService.getFeature() does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using dependency injection correctly. There is no `this` in static context.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable() // note this
export class FeatureService {
  constructor(protected http: Http) {}


  getFeature(){ // note: no "static" here. This is instance method. Service will be singleton anyway. 
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/features')
      .map(data => data.toString());
  }
}
```

You should rewrite providers declaration to `@NgModule` as others said. Your solution was correct for beta versions and will not work in current versions.

BTW, I hope this is just proof of concept implementation, as code quality is really low (no configurable endpoints, using http without service in component, no`@NgModule`, bad code formatting, deprecated/removed APIs, typos).

Comment: then I get : (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for FeatureService:

Comment: add imports for `Http` and `@Injectable`, I thought it is obvious. I updated by answer.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry very tired. But it works now thank yo very much

Answer (score 1):

do not include `providers: [FeatureService],` in component either inclulde it in `@NgModule`

basically it will crate new instance of service and ruin singleton pattern

Comment: Like this?: @NgModule({
  providers: [FeatureService]
})

Comment: yes try it @NgModule({ providers: [FeatureService] }) in your app.module.ts

Comment: thanks now the code is cleaner but the bug is still there

Comment: you have to include @Injectable in service

Comment: I just added it but it says it is unused and the error remains

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent {
  titel = "";
  leerling: any;
  leerlingUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/testresultaten';

    public clicked(){
      this.http.get(this.leerlingUrl).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => this.leerling = JSON.stringify(data)
          ,error => this.leerling = "error", () => console.log("Json got good"));
    }
    public getFeatures(){
      this.leerling = this.featureService.getFeature();
    }
    public getScenarios(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/features/1/scenarios').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => this.leerling = JSON.stringify(data),error => this.leerling = "error", () => console.log("Json got good"));
  }

    constructor(private http : Http, private featureService : FeatureService){
    }

 }
```

and service

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
@Injectable()
export class FeatureService{
  private static http : Http;


  getFeature(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/features')
      .map(data => data.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/2JQ1GNf9kaNtYuLMJsOz?p=preview it works in plunkr

Comment: I get that but I still get the same error I copied everthing imported injectable and made the http not static